# Can acoustic waves travel through human body?

Tags: waves, acoustics

If I stand inside [a perfect anechoic chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anechoic_chamber) in front of a unidirectional acoustic waves emitter, I would hear the tone played either using my ears or using a microphone for ultrasonic waves. But what happens if I put my hand in between my head/microphone and that emitter? Or if a person stands between me and the emitter?

Would I still hear/detect something?
And on what properties does the propagation or blocking depends on? frequency, signal energy?

Comment: How does a stethoscope work? What I mean is, how does the doctor hear your heartbeat, to address your  question in the title?

Comment: Acoustinc waves propagate through materials as physical vibrations. But what would happen if a wave beam is coming from outside the body? Is it fully reflected? Does it make the body vibrate and emit a damped version of the initial signal in all directions? or is the majority of the signal energy conserved and comes out from the other side of the human body as a beam? By travel through I  mean Out-In-Out and not just confined In !

Comment: Yes, I apologise, I couldn't resist the comment and  I thought of that afterwards:) I don't see why your body should not allow sound waves to pass right through it, as it's mostly water. How much distortion etc you would get, I don't know, it  depends on your individual body composition, (a fat dude like me would block most of it:)  but hopefully you will get an answer. Best of luck with it.

Comment: The sound wave can travel through our body. It will be damped of course, but it can still make it through if it is intense enough. Some waves will get reflected, others will be reflected and transmitted. Our body is like every other material. The wave propagation will depend on the geometry and the material components of our body, like the water inside.

Comment: @LandosAdam Hi Landos,  I would work that into an answer, if you have the time.

Comment: @count_to_10 Hello, I am happy I helped, although I am just taking a course on waves, so there might be someone in here that knows waves better than me and thus provide you with a more complete and detailed answer.

Comment: Ultrasound scans, in fact, use this principle. They use sound waves propagating through the body, and being partially reflected across a change in media, to image the body.

Comment: @HarshaVardhan exactly, they partially "reflect. That is why I was wondering if they propagate until the other side.

Comment: @Mehdi Yes, some amount has to propogate to the other side, although you can expect some amount of sound to 'diffract' around the object. Your question is especially valid in the case of media such as rubber with high attenuation coefficients, which is highly absorbing for acoustic waves.

Comment: Beside, don't confuse sound with light: low frequency waves have huge diffraction, i.e. there "rays" can bend alot around obstacles.  So the can that you "see" you hand as an obstacle doesn't means it is the same soundwise (beside the transmission accross the hand)

Answer (score 4):

First, *some* fraction of incident sound power will pass thru any object, human body or not, so your title makes no sense.  The real question is how much this body will attenuate the frequencies of interest.  Below some attenuation, you either don't care or it's below the noise floor of the sensors to detect it.  However, this depends on what you care about, how good your sensors are, and how much ambient noise there is, so there is no single yes/no answer.

The other part of what you are missing is that "blocking" by your hand isn't the issue.  A human body, even just a hand, will likely attenuate to oblivion audio frequencies coupled air to body and then back out body to air.  However, that won't prevent you hearing the sound in the setup you describe.  That's because of diffraction around the edges of this body, even if you assume it absorbes everything incident upon it.

If you figure audio frequencies are from 20 Hz to 20 kHz, and sound propagates thru normal air at about 3 ms per meter, then the wavelengths are 17 m to 17 mm.  Even at 17 mm, there will be easily audible diffraction that will go around the edges of the blocking object.  You will be able to hear significant attenuation as you hold your hand between your ear and the source, but you will still be able to hear the original.

Let's say your hand is about 100 mm across.  100 mm sound wavelength means about 3.3 kHz frequency.  That's roughly the limit below which the hand will have diminishing affect.  At 300 Hz, for example, you probably won't notice any affect from puting your hand in the way when it's arm's length from your head and the sound source.  At 1/10 wavelength, the sounds waves will mostly just go around it without getting attenuated.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will post a question soon in the engineering stack about the feasibility of range estimation between two synchronized ultrasonic emitter/receiver using phase shift, even with no direct line of sight, eg. a human is standing in between.